# Unexplainable mysql error when trying to CREATE ASSERTION

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am currently learning mysql, my implementation is MariaDB on Arch Linux, I posted the `STATUS` below in case it is relevant.

So here is the problem, I have this table:

```
MariaDB [biodb_sam]> SELECT * FROM pwms LIMIT 10;
+---------+-----+------+-------+
| tfs_id  | pos | base | value |
+---------+-----+------+-------+
| hPDI060 |   1 | A    |  0.01 |
| hPDI060 |   1 | C    |  0.01 |
| hPDI060 |   1 | G    |  0.97 |
| hPDI060 |   1 | T    |  0.01 |
| hPDI060 |   2 | A    |  0.01 |
| hPDI060 |   2 | C    |  0.48 |
| hPDI060 |   2 | G    |   0.5 |
| hPDI060 |   2 | T    |  0.01 |
| hPDI060 |   3 | A    | 0.625 |
| hPDI060 |   3 | C    |  0.01 |
+---------+-----+------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I want to add a simple assertion, to make sure `pos` is always positive, I get this error:

```
MariaDB [biodb_sam]> CREATE ASSERTION foo CHECK(NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pwms WHERE pos < 1));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASSERTION foo CHECK(NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pwms WHERE pos < 1))' at line 1
```

I do not see the difference with the example on MariaDB documentation [on this webpage](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/create-assertion-statement/). The `SELECT` statement in the check works fine on it's own, so the problem must be somewhere else, but I don't see it.

Anyway, here is the full server information:

```
MariaDB [biodb_sam]> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.10-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          52
Current database:       biodb_sam
Current user:           sam@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.1.10-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 1 day 16 hours 56 min 2 sec

Threads: 4  Questions: 6264  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 142  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 64  Queries per second avg: 0.0
42
--------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to quote what is on the top of the page you linked:

> This page is part of the book SQL-99 Complete, Really, by Peter Gulutzan & Trudy Pelzer. The authors have graciously allowed us to reproduce the contents of the book here. Because the book is about the SQL-99 standard, the contents of this and other pages in the book may not directly apply to MariaDB. Use the navigation bar to navigate the book.

MariaDB specific documentation is different. You can find the full list of supported [CREATE statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create/) on mariadb's website. This list does not include CREATE ASSERTION, so MariaDB does not support this functionality, hence the error message:

Articles on the various CREATE statements

- CREATE DATABASE Create a database
- CREATE EVENT
  Create and schedule a new event
  1
- CREATE FUNCTION
  Creates a stored function
- CREATE FUNCTION UDF
  Create a user-defined function
- CREATE INDEX
  Create an index on one or more columns
- CREATE PROCEDURE
  Creates a stored procedure
- CREATE ROLE
  Add new roles
- CREATE SERVER
  Define a server
  5
- CREATE TABLE
  Creating a new table
- CREATE TABLESPACE
  CREATE TABLESPACE is not available in MariaDB
- CREATE TRIGGER
  Create a new trigger
- CREATE USER
  Create new MariaDB accounts
- CREATE VIEW
  Create or replace a view

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed a bit too quick to skip that. What would be the best alternative to use for this in MariaDB?

Comment: In general this feature is not supported. Period. However, in this particular case, you can declare the pos field to be unsigned integer type, and then no negative values can be assigned to it. Even if mariadb were to support the check constraint, I would use an unsigned integer type to achieve the desired results. It's a lot more effective from a performance point of view.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use check constraint instead of this but this don't work in mysql. As I am thinking, I have got one idea that create an unsigned integer as type for this column to avoid negative values.

Comment: Neither mysql, nor mariadb support check constraint. If there is a check constraint in the create table statement, then mysql parses it (so no syntax error is generated), but is silently ignored. I guess, mariadb does the same thing.

Comment: Ya that is good information for me, thanks I will edit my answer.